# Tracking model changes in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, unit-of-work

I want to log every action what will be done with some SQLAlchemy-Models.

So, I have a after_insert, after_delete and before_update hooks, where I will save previous and current representation of model,

```
def keep_logs(cls):
    @event.listens_for(cls, 'after_delete')
    def after_delete_trigger(mapper, connection, target):
        pass

    @event.listens_for(cls, 'after_insert')
    def after_insert_trigger(mapper, connection, target):
        pass

    @event.listens_for(cls, 'before_update')
    def before_update_trigger(mapper, connection, target):
        prev = cls.query.filter_by(id=target.id).one()
        # comparing previous and current model


MODELS_TO_LOGGING = (
    User,
)
for cls in MODELS_TO_LOGGING:
    keep_logs(cls)
```

But there is one problem: when I'm trying to find model in before_update hook, SQLA returns modified (dirty) version.
How can I get previous version of model before updating it? 
Is there a different way to keep model changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

SQLAlchemy tracks the changes to each attribute.  You don't need to (and shouldn't) query the instance again in the event.  Additionally, the event is triggered for any instance that has been modified, even if that modification will not change any data.  Loop over each column, checking if it has been modified, and store any new values.

```
@event.listens_for(cls, 'before_update')
def before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    state = db.inspect(target)
    changes = {}

    for attr in state.attrs:
        hist = attr.load_history()

        if not hist.has_changes():
            continue

        # hist.deleted holds old value
        # hist.added holds new value
        changes[attr.key] = hist.added

    # now changes map keys to new values
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem but wanted to be able to keep track of the deltas as changes are made to sqlalchemy models instead of just the new values. I wrote this slight extension to [davidism's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400617/davidism) answer to do that along with slightly better handling of `before` and `after`, since they are lists sometimes or empty tuples other times:

```py
  from sqlalchemy import inspect

  def get_model_changes(model):
    """
    Return a dictionary containing changes made to the model since it was 
    fetched from the database.

    The dictionary is of the form {'property_name': [old_value, new_value]}

    Example:
      user = get_user_by_id(420)
      >>> '<User id=402 email="business_email@gmail.com">'
      get_model_changes(user)
      >>> {}
      user.email = 'new_email@who-dis.biz'
      get_model_changes(user)
      >>> {'email': ['business_email@gmail.com', 'new_email@who-dis.biz']}
    """
    state = inspect(model)
    changes = {}
    for attr in state.attrs:
      hist = state.get_history(attr.key, True)

      if not hist.has_changes():
        continue

      old_value = hist.deleted[0] if hist.deleted else None
      new_value = hist.added[0] if hist.added else None
      changes[attr.key] = [old_value, new_value]

    return changes

  def has_model_changed(model):
    """
    Return True if there are any unsaved changes on the model.
    """
    return bool(get_model_changes(model))
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! My only feedback would be to consider a variation on this naming. get_model_changes -> get_instance_changes. Rather than pass in `model` pass in `instance`.  This differentiates from the a model's general class definition.

Answer (score 4):

If an attribute is expired (which sessions do by default on commit) the old value is not available unless it was loaded before being changed. You can see this with the inspection.

```py
state = inspect(entity)
session.commit()
state.attrs.my_attribute.history  # History(added=None, unchanged=None, deleted=None)
# Load history manually
state.attrs.my_attribute.load_history()
state.attrs.my_attribute.history  # History(added=(), unchanged=['my_value'], deleted=())
```

In order for attributes to stay loaded you can not expire entities by settings `expire_on_commit` to False on the session.