# Tracking changes in SQLAlchemy model and getting json_body user_id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using code like below from the post of [Tracking model changes in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921260/tracking-model-changes-in-sqlalchemy). The only issue I am currently having is my map gets the end user's username through a token and I need to pass that username info into this function so it is logged with the changes. Is there a better method or do I just need to add a column to my tables called last modified by and just scrape that with this listener on update to the table?

```
@event.listens_for(cls, 'before_update')
def before_udpate(mapper, connection, target):
    state = db.inspect(target)
    changes = {}

    for attr in state.attrs:
        hist = state.get_history(attr.key, True)

        if not hist.has_changes():
            continue

        # hist.deleted holds old value
        # hist.added holds new value
        changes[attr.key] = hist.added

        # now changes map keys to new values
```

Or is there some type of way that I can call this information from my view?

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on this for the night. I came up with doing a mixin. Similar to what is on this page: http://francesco.pischedda.info/posts/logging-model-changes-with-sqlalchemy-listeners.html

I pass in my request object so that my target object will have the request object.