# Caching a table state using SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a table that won't change very frequently and hence I wish to cache it at the client side. So is there some sort of *hash value* or *last update time* which can be used to determine if the table is updated? If not, then how can I create a trigger to track the changes in tables?
Python - SQL Alchemy, Fast API, Postgres SQL

```
class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
    id:    int = Column(Integer,    primary_key=True)
class State(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'state'
    id:    int = Column(Integer,    primary_key=True)

class Cache(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cache'
    index:          int      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name:     str      = Column(String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    sync_token:     str      = Column(String(40), nullable=False)

# triggers
@event.listens_for(Country, 'after_update')
def after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    pass '''on any change in this table update the timestamp in the cache table'''
```

Comment: Although your case is quite static - better do not do that. Building and maintaining/synchronizing many sets of state (as many as client sessions there are) is hard and expensive. It is a slippery road that will never pay off. Abide by the 'single source of truth' rule and keep only one state - in the database.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm The tables won't change much - like the name and number of states in a country is very unlikely to change. I want this because if in any remote possibility shall it change, then the client should be able to reflect the same changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your table column that update timestamp when any modification in the table would have been made:

```py
    from datetime import datetime
    from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, func

    modified_at = Column(
        DateTime,
        server_default=func.timezone("UTC", func.now()),
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow,
    )
```

You can also use events to track changes in your table. Here is a topic covering it: [Tracking model changes in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921260/tracking-model-changes-in-sqlalchemy)

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# triggers
@event.listens_for(Country, 'after_update')
def after_update(mapper, connection, target):
   # target is your updated Country instance
   connection.execute(f"update cache set index = {target.int} where table_name = 'country'")
   # last_update_on will be modified automatically
```

Comment: I wish to horizontally scale this solution. I think triggers are the best bet as it is not dependent on SQL Alchemy. I don't think adding the *modified_at* column to the tables I need to cache is going to solve this particular problem. If you think it does then kindly explain how.

Comment: `modified_at` was an answer to this: "So is there some sort of hash value or last update time which can be used to determine if the table is updated?". You can use: trigger at db layer, events at sqlalchemy or some kind of local event bus: https://github.com/Enforcer/pybuses. You need some kind of CQRS solution. What do you mean horizontally? Horizontal nodes of application would use the same database?

Comment: Yes, a single database accessed by multiple nodes running the same python application. Yes using a trigger or event would be the right method to get this done, but not sure how to write a trigger or event. Can you modify your answer with an abstract example ? (I have edited the question) Thanks.

Comment: I write an answer but I am not sure whether your model of Country/State and Cache is proper

Comment: The column *sync_token* will contain an SHA-1 string which will change when every time the table with *table_name* is updated. I have managed to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cache(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cache'
    index:          int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name:     str = Column(String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)   
    last_update_on: datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)

# triggers
@event.listens_for(Country, 'after_update')
def run_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    dateTime:  str = str(datetime.now())
    tableName: str = Country.__tablename__
    update_stmt = f"UPDATE cache SET last_update_on = '{dateTime}' WHERE table_name = '{tableName}'"
    connection.execute(update_stmt)
```